# Binary search of words in python list

Tags: python, list, search, binary-search

I have two lists of words to compare. First list is 2 million words, second list is 150,000 words. What I need to do is to apply binary search to see if words of the first list appear in the second. I was trying liner search:

```
for word in words_list:
    if word in dict_list:
       print(word, 1)
    else:
       print(word, 0)
```

It works good, but it is very slow.
Then I tried binary search but it did not work correctly:

```
for word in wordlist:
    lb = 0
    ub = len(dict_list)
    mid_index = (lb + ub) // 2
    item_at_mid = dict_list[mid_index]
    if item_at_mid == word:
        print(word)
    if item_at_mid < word:
        lb = mid_index + 1
    else:
        ub = mid_index
```

In the end I need two list first list of words that are in dictionary and second that are not.

Comment: linux command will do that for you
`cmp file1 file2`

Comment: Are you actually printing the values, or is this for demonstation? Printing is super slow compared to putting the elements into two new lists.

Comment: it is a demostrationa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a Binary Search:

```
present = []
absent = []
for word in firstList:
    lb,ub = 0,len(secondList) - 1
    found = False
    while lb <= ub:
        mid = (lb + ub) // 2
        if secondList[mid] == word:
            found = True
            break
        elif secondList[mid] < word:
            lb = mid + 1
        else:
            ub = mid - 1

    if found:
        present.append(word)
    else:
        absent.append(word)
```

Your binary search code was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets:

```
inter = set(words_list).intersection(dict_list)
for word in words_list:
    if word in inter:
        print(word, 1)
    else:
        print(word, 0)
```

Comment: I do not have dictionary I have 2 lists.

Comment: OK, so just use dict_list.keys() -> dict_list. I thought it's a dict because of the name. edited

Answer (score 1):

If you are using binary search your input should have been ordered. 
One other possibility is convert your `words_list` and `dict_list` to `set` and get the output as follows:

words common to both:

```
words_list.intersection(dict_list)
```

words not in one other:

```
words_list-dict_list
dict_list-words_list
```

Comment: From the wording it is implied he can get away with only making a set out of `words_list`. Then using `intersection()` and `difference()` and passing `dict_list` as a list will achieve the same result.

Comment: @Reti43: I was thinking same. Later i looked at the comments of previous answer which confirms only the name contains the word `dict` but actually it is `list`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to prefer using `set` instead of list, because of the `O(1)` complexity for `__contains__` operation, as given in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36423241/3077939).

If memory is a problem, then using a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is probably a good tradeoff (no false negative).

[Here is a python implementation](https://github.com/jaybaird/python-bloomfilter/).

---

To create and maintain a binary tree, consider using [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html) standard module.